# getting default value of registrykey via powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

Why does this work:

```
$regbase = "HKLM:\Software\Python\PythonCore"
if (!(Test-Path $regbase)) {return}
(dir -Path "$regbase\*\InstallPath") | gp | select -ExpandProperty "(default)"
```

but not this:

```
(dir -Path "$regbase\*\InstallPath") | gp -Name "(default)"
```

I thought that was what the *-Name* option on **Get-ItemProperty** was for.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's pretty unintuitive. The PS Registry provider leaves a few things to be desired.

The main thing to remember is that Get-ItemProperty -Name '(default)' gets the property itself (represented as a pscustomobject), not the value of the property.